# Using gnu autoconf, is there a way to build into a sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, autoconf

In this case, it's GPG that I'm trying to build. Basically, I want to have all the build output go into a subdirectory of my choosing, instead of being installed on my live filesystem.

Setting --prefix=*path/to/my/sandbox* sends the output of one build where I want it to go, but the next build stage, which depends on the output of the previous build stage, can't find that output.

Example:

```
$ cd libgpg-error-1.37
$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
  (success: all output placed in /Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/)
$ cd ../libassuan-2.5.3
$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local
...
configure: error: libgpg-error was not found
$
```

Is there another option I could have passed to ./configure to get it to find libraries in the sandbox? Should I build inside a VM or a docker container?

Comment: `--prefix` just tells where the built thing should be installed. It basically has no effect before `make install`. So if you want to use libraries from non-standard location, you need to use other options of `configure` script to provide them. Try `./configure --help`.

Comment: Yep; I know that --prefix just redirects the build artifacts. I'm just wondering if there's a way to tell configure where else to search for required components. I didn't realize that configure had a --help option.

Comment: Here's one way, not specific to `configure`: https://askubuntu.com/q/386315/192226

Comment: That helped a lot. Executive summary: set `export CPPFLAGS='-I/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/include'`, set `export LDFLAGS='-L/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/lib'` and add /Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/bin to your path.

Comment: OK, it all worked a treat. I was able to generate a tarball with my built software that's the next best thing to a real installation package. (Ultimately, if you have homebrew installed on your Mac, it's best to just use that rather than rolling your own packages, but I had my reasons.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @hyde for pointing me in the right direction. The solution was to set a few environment variables before building:

```
mkdir -p /Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/
export CPPFLAGS='-I/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/include'
export LDFLAGS='-L/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/lib'
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local/bin"
cd libgpg-error-1.37/
./configure --prefix=/Users/falk/GpgSandbox/usr/local
make install
(etc.)
```